# Python querying last record in sql db, but returning blank record

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using Python Flask and SQLAlchemy to create a simple web app that stores a user's input for a book's ISBN (ISBN = a unique book id) in a db table, and then queries that record later to use in an API call. It uses the API response to store the book info in another table.

I have confirmed that the tables are storing data properly. I have confirmed that querying the ISBN table returns the correct values. But when I try to store the query as a Python variable and use it in the API call, it always acts like the variable is == ''.

Here's the database setup:

```
class Isbn(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    isbn = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, isbn):
        self.isbn = isbn
```

Here's the route for querying the ISBN table, using the ISBN record in the API call, and then storing the result of that data in another table:

```
@app.route('/addbook', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def addbook():
    title = "Addbook"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        isbn = db.session.query(Isbn.isbn).order_by(Isbn.id).first()
        r = urllib.request.urlopen(f'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:{isbn}')
        data = json.load(r)
        btitle = data["items"][0]["volumeInfo"]["title"]
        author = data["items"][0]["volumeInfo"]["authors"][0]
        pagecount = data["items"][0]["volumeInfo"]["pageCount"]
        newbook = Books(title=btitle, author=author, pagecount=pagecount)
        db.session.add(newbook)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/searchbook')
```

Earlier in the app I use the same method of using user input in the API call, and it works fine. I have taken out the error handling here but the error is saying the API response has no body to it, and upon research I found it is because the ISBN table query returns ''.

Comment: Instead of `db.session.query(Isbn.isbn).order_by(Isbn.id).first()` try `db.session.query(Isbn.isbn).order_by(Isbn.id).scalar()`

Comment: @GordThompson it gave me this error: sqlalchemy.exc.MultipleResultsFound: Multiple rows were found when exactly one was required. I do need only one result, which is the ISBN value from the record.

Comment: Hmm. Okay, then how about `… .order_by(Isbn.id).first().isbn` ?

Comment: @GordThompson that worked!! Can you explain why it worked so I won't go through this headache next time? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when querying for a single element, `.first()` returns a SQLAlchemy `Row` object which acts very much like a named tuple

```py
isbn = session.query(Isbn.isbn).order_by(Isbn.id).first()
print(type(isbn))  # <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row'>
print(isbn)  # (9783161484100,)
```

Notice that the string representation includes the parentheses and the comma, so embedding that into a URL will produce

```py
print(f"https://…?q=isbn:{isbn}")  # https://…?q=isbn:(9783161484100,)
```

which may not work because of the unexpected characters.

Since `Row` objects act like named tuples we can access their elements by name, e.g., `my_row.my_column`, so we can use

```py
isbn = session.query(Isbn.isbn).order_by(Isbn.id).first().isbn
print(type(isbn))  # <class 'int'>
print(isbn)  # 9783161484100

print(f"https://…?q=isbn:{isbn}")  # https://…?q=isbn:9783161484100
```